# How to compute git blob sha of a string using golang

Tags: git, go, sha

Given a string, how to compute **git** BLOB SHA on it. I tried computing the sha on string using api provided by golang but it is not matching with git blob sha.

How to get the sha same as git blob sha using golang

Answer (score 0):

The way blob sha is calculated by git is a bit different. It prepends a header `blob <length>\x00<content>`

Here `<length>` is the byte length of content, `\x00` is the ending delimiter and `<content>` is the actual content string.

I've created the below function which returns the git blob sha of a given string

```
func computeGitBlobSHA(s string) string {
    p := fmt.Sprintf("blob %d\x00", len(s))
    h := sha1.New()
    h.Write([]byte(p))
    h.Write([]byte(s))
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum([]byte(nil)))
}
```

so calling `computeGitBlobSHA("Hello")` will return `5ab2f8a4323abafb10abb68657d9d39f1a775057` which is the actual git sha.

Check this on [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/s2_VWMsBvan)

If you want, you can verify it using `echo -n 'Hello' | git hash-object --stdin`